# Two scripts using same login and database

Tags: php, authentication

I have two php scripts "Made by the same person" I have them both calling the same mysql database and combined all the tables. Right now its using the same table for the login. So I can login with my same username and password for both but when I log in to the main site and then go to the other script /client. It wants me to login again.

I know I have to include something or hold a session or something (I am not good at php). So I want to be able to login to the main site and go to /client and still be logged in. Any ideas?

Update: 
They both have a /lib/class_user.php which is where I believe the session is started, here is some of the code at the top:

From main site:

```
 /**
   * Users::startSession()
   * 
   * @return
   */
  private function startSession()
  {
    if (strlen(session_id()) < 1)
        session_start();

    $this->logged_in = $this->loginCheck();

    if (!$this->logged_in) {
        $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] = "Guest";
        $this->sesid = sha1(session_id());
        $this->userlevel = 0;
    }
  }

/**
   * Users::loginCheck()
   * 
   * @return
   */
  private function loginCheck()
  {
      if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] != "Guest") {

          $row = $this->getUserInfo($_SESSION['username']);
          $this->uid = $row['id'];
          $this->username = $row['username'];
          $this->email = $row['email'];
          $this->name = $row['fname'].' '.$row['lname'];
          $this->userlevel = $row['userlevel'];
          $this->sesid = sha1(session_id());
          $this->membership_id = $row['membership_id'];
          $this->access = $row['access'];
          return true;
      } else {
          return false;
      }  
  }

  /**
   * Users::is_Admin()
   * 
   * @return
   */
  public function is_Admin()
  {
      return($this->userlevel == 9 or $this->userlevel == 8);

  }
```

From /client/lib/class_user.php:

```
  /**
   * Users::startSession()
   * 
   * @return
   */
  private function startSession()
  {
      session_start();
      $this->logged_in = $this->loginCheck();

      if (!$this->logged_in) {
          $this->username = $_SESSION['username'] = "Guest";
          $this->sesid = sha1(session_id());
          $this->userlevel = 0;
      }
  }

  /**
   * Users::loginCheck()
   * 
   * @return
   */
  private function loginCheck()
  {
      if (isset($_SESSION['username']) && $_SESSION['username'] != "Guest") {

          $row = $this->getUserInfo($_SESSION['username']);
          $this->uid = $row->id;
          $this->username = $row->username;
          $this->email = $row->email;
          $this->name = $row->fname . ' ' . $row->lname;
          $this->userlevel = $row->userlevel;
          $this->sesid = sha1(session_id());
      $this->currency = $row->currency;
          return true;
      } else {
          return false;
      }
  }

  /**
   * Users::is_Admin()
   * 
   * @return
   */
  public function is_Admin()
  {
      return ($this->userlevel == 9 or $this->userlevel == 5);

  }
```

Comment: Are the two sites on the same domain? Session cookies (like all cookies) are domain specific. If the two sites are subdomains of the same domain, or one is a sub of the other, you can set a cookie at the higher domain.

Comment: can you show some coding ??????

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that the two scripts are setting different $_SESSION variables. This will show you what's being set if you put it somewhere like the bottom of the page template (or each page if you're not using a templating system):

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_SESSION);
echo "</pre>";
```

Comment: from main page:   Array
(
    [username] => admin
    [uid] => 1
    [email] => mbeasley@matthewbeasley.net
    [userlevel] => 9
    [membership_id] => 4
    [access] => 
)

Comment: from client page  Array
(
    [username] => admin
    [captchacode] => 81808
    [userid] => 1
    [email] => mbeasley@matthewbeasley.net
    [userlevel] => 9
    [currency] => 
)
Select Form Option

Comment: It looks like your main page is using $_SESSION['uid'] & your client page is using $_SESSION['userid'] for verification. So, in order to make single login across both work, you can either make your verification scripts use the same variable or you could make them check that either variable is set.

Comment: Which code tag do you mean? Assuming you mean the code tag in the question editor then you can only use it for the body of your question (or an answer) - so if you have more detail for instance then edit your original question & add any code there. (apologies if I've misunderstood).

Comment: Also made them both uid but still no luck, posted some code above.